# Кнопка с номером телефона Telegram

Tags: telegram

Делаю бота для телеграм, нужно сделать инлайн кнопку, при нажатии на которой она срабатывала аналогично Позвонить 
Есть InlineKeyboardButton с параметром url но есть туда передать "tel:+7123231423",  выдается error:

{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL"}

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать это через Inline Button, и если нет, то как передать кликабельный номер в тексте сообщения?

Comment: Достаточно просто указать номер и все будет открываться без проблем.

Answer (score -1):

давай через "грязный хак": создаешь файл https://moydomen.ru/call.php
В котором такая запись:

header("Location: tel:787770099");

А кнопку ссылаешь на выше указанный адрес